# How to edit the select form arrow? (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on a form with Bootstrap 4 and I would like to edit/change the style of the arrow select element from the first version to the second version as depicted below.

[image]

I tried different ways (as seen in this community *citations needed*) to edit the arrow but I had no success.

Could someone help me by explaining how I could achieve the desired result?

Please find bellow an example of my HTML for the problem.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta content="Description" name="description">
  <meta content="index,follow" name="robots">
  <link href="/images/myicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
  <title>TITLE HERE</title>
  <!--CSS-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You should use some custom `select` dropdown e.g. selectyze, select2 etc. You can customise the look using css then.

Comment: you can not change its default behaviour .. use other third party tool for your requirement

Comment: try this would help `margin-top:10px;
  border-top:15px red solid;
  border-right: 15px transparent solid;
  border-left: 15px transparent solid;
  border-bottom:15px transparent solid;`

Comment: Yes you can change it .. I found the answer here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#select-menu

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have found the answer on the same Bootstrap 4

```html
<select class="custom-select">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Link: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#select-menu

Thank you for the help anyway

Comment: Not very useful in helping one position the caret.

Comment: This actually changed the look of the arrow (what I needed), so thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Just an example. You can use it as reference.

In this example you will learn the way to custom the selectbox. However, in my experience. Old browsers doesn't support this method.

```css
select {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, red 60%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, red 40%, transparent 50%) !important;
  background-position:
    calc(100% - 30px) 14px,
    calc(100% - 20px) 14px,
    100% 0;
  background-size:
    10px 10px,
    10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The .custom-select class is already there (Bootstrap 4). To change the arrow of the select input you just override the background property. So for example:

```
.custom-select { background: none; }
```

removes the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use Select2, the solution will be simple by adding costum class like :

```
$("#myList").select2({
     containerCssClass: "customClass"
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#myList").select2({
     containerCssClass: "customClass"
 });
```

```css
/* select2 version 4.0.0 Beta 2 */
.select2-container--default .customClass.select2-selection--single{
  border-radius: 24px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.select2-container--default .customClass.select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{
  border-color: #00b37c transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  margin-left: -22px;
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open .customClass.select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{
  border-color: transparent transparent #00b37c;
  border-width: 0px 8px 8px;
  margin-left: -22px;
}

.select2-container--default .customClass.select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{
  padding-top: 5px;
  height: 35px;
}

.select2-container--default .customClass.select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{
  color: #00b37c;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>


<select id="myList" style="width:300px">
  <option value="A">Protection Form</option>
  <option value="B">Option 2</option>
  <option value="C">Option 3</option>
  <option value="D">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice! Great answer since he's using bootstrap. I assume that he's also including jQuery. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Since Bootstrap allows us to custom via variables. In this case, I would suggest to define icon via *$custom-select-indicator* variable.

```
$custom-select-indicator: url(path-to-icon) !default;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your css file

```
select {
  background-image:url("url of icon") !important;
  background-position:calc(100% - 20px) 14px,100% 0;
  background-size:20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```