# I want to remove the default arrow and place my on image instead of arrow in dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-selectpicker

**CSS**

```
  .bootstrap-select {
    width: 300px !important;
   
  }
  /* .bootstrap-select::after {
    content: none;
  }
     */
    
  .btn-custom {
    color: black;
    /* background-color: blue; */
    border-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .btn-custom::after {
    content: url(/extras/drop.png);
    /* width: 95%; */
  }
  .btn-custom::before {
    content: none;
  }
 .bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder.btn-custom,
  .bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder.btn-custom:hover,
  .bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder.btn-custom:focus,
  .bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder.btn-custom:active {
    color: black;
  }
```

**HTML** `enter code here`

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-custom" multiple data-max-options="4" data-actions-box="true">
                        <option>Mustard</option>
                        <option>Ketchup</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                      </select>
```

**Bootstrap Cdn version 4.1.1**
[my select feild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT0jN.png)
I want to use my image instead of the arrow on the field and want to remove the default icon or any other way I can use it??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit the select form arrow? (Bootstrap 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363405/how-to-edit-the-select-form-arrow-bootstrap-4)

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate.